# For Loop or Function to Conditionally Subtract values of Two Columns

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have two columns in a data frame:

```
x    y
0    1000
0    1000
4    1000
2    1000
10   1000
5    1000
```

What I want to do is write a for loop or function (whichever is more efficient) that can loop through every cell in y, subtract this value by the value of x in the same row and input the result into a new column "z".

The trick is I want a condition where it remembers what the last calculated value of z is every time so that it is constantly remembering the last result of the loop or function and subtracts x from that rather than the same value of y every time as y is always constant. What this would look like would be:

Output:

```
x    y       z
0    1000    1000
0    1000    1000
4    1000    996
2    1000    **994** #rather than 998
10   1000    **984**
5    1000    **979**
```

The purpose of this is to measure decomposition in the sample size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take the cumulative sum of 'x' column and subtract from the 'y' to create the 'z' column

```
df1$z <- with(df1, y - cumsum(x))
df1$z
#[1] 1000 1000  996  994  984  979
```

Comment: That worked great. However I made a mistake when I first described the data. Apparently the y column values change every 10 rows. Is there a way to write a loop or function that restarts every N rows? An example would be the the first 10 rows of y are 1000 then it changes to 2000. I don't want the cumulative sum for x to carry over after the first 10 rows to the new value of y.

Comment: @Kardinol  You can create a group b for every 10 rows.  i.e `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 10, n()))) %>% mutate(z = y - cumsum(x))`

Comment: If your y column does not consistently change every 10 rows you could try this: `for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {df$z[i]=ifelse(i==1,df$y[i]-df$x[i],ifelse(df$y[i]==df$y[i-1],df$y[i]-cumsum(df$x[i]),df$y[i]-df$x[i]))}`